# PHP not running on apache server

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am new to PHP, and relatively new to Apache. 
For my server, I am using a raspberry pi running Ubuntu MATE, which (as far as I know) is just Ubuntu with a different desktop environment. I have PHP installed, and the file I'm serving is a .php file, NOT html. 
I am trying to execute PHP code on my test page, which is just served locally. I know that I need to edit the config file for Apache in order for it to run, but I don't know how; all of the various answers and articles I have looked at the past few days are either for Windows or for a much older version of Apache. I have tried many of them, and they all either result in nothing changing or an error when trying to restart Apache.
The PHP code I'm using looks like this:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "Hello!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the inspector in Firefox, the PHP code is commented out, a clear indication that it is not being executed.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you think apache is not properly configure?

Comment: Your problem is obviously not code related. It is a server issue. Try a search for "php ubuntu raspberry pi". Fix the server first.

Comment: @gbengawale Yes, that is definitely the issue. The problem is that I don’t know how to do that

Comment: @theratkeeper To check that Apache is up and running on your Raspberry Pi, you can enter the Raspberry Pi’s IP address into a web browser. The server should return a webpage with some simple text on it.

Comment: If you don’t know the IP, you can enter the following command into the terminal to retrieve it with this command  hostname -I

Comment: I can access the page; I have already done it (both on the pi itself and on another computer in the network)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that,

- you have either not installed `libapache2-mod-php7.x` module
- OR not enabled module.
- OR you installed module but not reloaded apache services

Below will help you

```
# verify whether module activated if not follow below
# if there were no module you will get No module matches php7.x
a2query -m php7.x

# install version of your php example 7.4
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.x  

# activate module
sudo a2enmod php7.x

# restart or reload apache 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Example in my case**

```
root@ideapad:~#  a2query -m php7.4
php7.4 (enabled by site administrator)

# if modules were loaded properly then you will see like below
root@ideapad:~#  ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php* -1
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.4.load
```

Comment: Oh, I think I may need to update things. I am using PHP 7.2 for some reason (I installed it Saturday)

Comment: I also don’t know if I have it enabled, but I have restarted Apache (a lot of times, actually, which is how I know I kept breaking it.

Comment: @theratkeeper please check

Comment: So it turned out that while I had enabled PHP previously, I forgot to re-enable it after and uninstalled and reinstalled Apache after I broke it trying to change the page from index.html to index.php. I enabled it and it worked, but I had to disable mpm_event first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem,Eventhough my apache was running it just rendered raw codes on the browser; after debugging  it manually and searching through the internet I finally got it solved. About two simple things fixed mine "though they weren't simple before I did them:)".

Btw I am running running PHP v7.4.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php

If you haven't installed PHP or Apache on your machine; you can check out this site for how to go about it for PHP version 7.4.3  [Linuxhint](https://linuxhint.com/install-php-7-linux/)